# Deploy Failed when Deploy on google App Engine (for upload on app engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sdk, java-7

When I run project on local system, project deploy successfully and running properly
but when i deploy it to Google App Engine (for upload on google app engine so every one can access site) it's failed. It's show me

```
------------ Deploying frontend ------------
Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\DOCUME~1\MASTER~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\appcfg8421561925415091473.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.

Debugging information may be found in C:\Documents and Settings\Master - Admin\Local Settings\Temp\appengine-deploy5746895533940558879.log
```

[image: Error message image]

but i am already using jdk, You can see it in below image.

[image: JDK Library]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully deploy project on google App Engine

I just add following line in eclipse shortcut (eclipse.ini)

```
-vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\javaw.exe"
```

or if you don't like to do this then you can
go to run and write following:

```
[path]eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\javaw.exe"
```

Note: If 'eclipse.exe -vm ...' directly not work then replace [path] with eclipse path
C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\javaw.exe"