# Google app engine deploy does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

Im am trying to deploy the app engine sample Guestbook. I selected JDK instead of jre in the paths as this is required to remove the error of the guestbook.jsp file. But now I am trying to deploy the app and i got this message:

Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.

I read that I have to add the lines below to the eclipse.ini:

-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\javaw.exe

But after doing this my eclipse wont start anymore.

I get this:

[image]

I dont know what to do now, so any help is welcome :)

Comment: possible duplicate see [Deploy Failed when Deploy on google App Engine (for upload on app engine)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404733/deploy-failed-when-deploy-on-google-app-engine-for-upload-on-app-engine)

Comment: Looks like you have a 32 bit Java and a 64 bit Eclipse - they must be both 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem and the app is now successfully deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your **eclipse is 64 bit but your pointing to the 32 bit** VM. Please correct the version issue and it will be resolved.

Make sure that a 32 bit Eclipse points to a 32 bit VM or, a 64 bit Eclipse points to a 64 bit VM.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem really silly, but I believe that the '-vm' and path should be on two different lines.. You can see the official wiki http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini for info.

Example:

[..]

--launcher.appendVmargs

**-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe**

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

-Xms40m

-Xmx512m

[..]

Can you try this and confirm?

Comment: I have those on two different lines ;) tried to edit it in my question but doesnt work.